Flutter fullscreen
Excuse me, I'm new to Flutter and I'm creating an application that needs to utilize fullscreen mode but also be able to exit it. The only issue with my code is that it forces fullscreen mode at all times, and I would like to give the user the ability to exit fullscreen mode by pressing F11 or ESC. Could you please advise and help?
Runapp
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized();
  windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) async {
    await windowManager.setFullScreen(true);
    await windowManager.show();
  });
}



Is this windows or mac?

It's a windows app

Can you try this code? You can change the code as per your need.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized();
  windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) async {
    await windowManager.setFullScreen(true);
    await windowManager.show();
  });
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fullScreenToggle() {
      windowManager
          .isFullScreen()
          .then((value) => windowManager.setFullScreen(!value));
    }

    return CallbackShortcuts(
      bindings: <ShortcutActivator, VoidCallback>{
        const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.f11): fullScreenToggle,
        const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.escape): fullScreenToggle,
      },
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text('Hello World!'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


